# How can I dynamically change the order ID from drag-and-drop on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on drag-and-drop to collect data in my database, so what I need is to open the website again and the item is in order from the last process.

My work done so far: I can collect the card and send it to the database perfectly fine, but my last problem is about sorting. I need to reorder the card in the same lane, but how can I collect the position of the card in the order?

Edit:: Okay, i figure out that $index can represent the order, but how can i get ng-event from ?